# How can I add class to parent if child contains class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to a parent DIV if it has a child IMG element with class of "testing".

```
<article>
    <div id="on-1" class="box">
        <img src="110.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="present">
        <img class="testing" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
</article>
```

I have set up `if` statement to check if class "testing" exists. I am having trouble adding class to the parent "article" element though.

```
if ($("article").find(".testing").length > 0) {
    $(.this.parentNode.parentNode).addClass("hasclass");
}
```

Comment: try `$(this).parent().addClass()`

Answer (score 5):

Use [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select parent element.

```
$("article img.testing").parent().addClass('hasclass');
```

```js
$("article img.testing").parent().addClass('hasclass');
```

```css
.hasclass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div id="on-1" class="box">
    <img src="110.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="present">
    <img class="testing" src="image.jpg">
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Like this, however need double .parent to add class to article

$("article").find(".testing").parent().parent().addClass('hasclass');

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div:has(img.testing)').addClass('hasclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on @Tushar's answer, to help elaborate on traversing up many parent nodes, I usually take the following approach:

To add a class to the direct parent `div`:

```
$('article img.testing').parent().toggleClass('new-class', true);
```

And to add the class to the encompassing `article` parent:

```
$('article img.testing').parents('article:first').toggleClass('new-class', true);
```

I also like using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) as it seems 'cleaner' to avoid any chance of adding the same class twice to an element, although I'm sure jQuery would check for this.

Hope this helps!