# How to add some html class to specific div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The bellow html is dynamic . There can be `n` numbers of `<ul>/<li>` like this.

Here What I need to do is if one of `li` class is `active` then only this parent `ul` should have class `show` like this `<div class="collapse show">`.

How can I do this with jquery ?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="hasSub" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
      <ul class="menu pl-3 mt-0">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">Text2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Add class to parent if child contains class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870257/jquery-add-class-to-parent-if-child-contains-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can use the `:has()` selector to target the `div` which contain the `li.active` element and add the class to them:

```js
$('div.collapse:has(ul > li.active)')
  .addClass('show')
  .find('.hasSub').addClass('active');
```

```css
div { display: none; }
div.show { display: block; }
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="hasSub" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
      <ul class="menu pl-3 mt-0">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">Text2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="hasSub" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <ul class="menu pl-3 mt-0">
        <li>
          <a href="">Hidden Text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Hidden Text2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to add  class active to this`class="hasSub"` also . How can I do it

Comment: You can use `find()` for that. I updated the example to show you

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $('li.active').parent('div.collapse').addClass('show');
    
    });

</script>
```